# How to run the downloaded project through eclipse

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, download

I am referring "http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/01/spring-mvc-3-hibernate-annotations.html" blog and at end of the blog there is **source code** in zip folder i have downloaded but i dont know how to run in **Eclipse**,
at the last on blog they have mention 
**You can run the project directly using an embedded server via Maven.

For Tomcat: mvn tomcat:run

For Jetty: mvn jetty:run**

I dont know how use this steps.please help me how to run this project,
I am using tomcat as my server,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do two things:

1. Install maven plugin in eclipse.
2. Add a tomcat server instance in eclipse.

This link should guide you to achieve that:

http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-maven

Comment: Instead of installing the mavenplugin in eclipse (that can be painful), you van download Springsource STS. This is an free preconfigured eclipse with an already installed maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Maven
2. go through command line to your project folder
3. call `mvn tomcat:run` or `mvn jetty:run`

Answer (score 0):

1.Install Maven

2.set system enivorment

3.go through command line to your project folder(where the pom.xml is)

4.call mvn tomcat:run or mvn jetty:run

Answer (score 0):

Download Spring Source Tool suite which comes along with maven. It maked things little easier for you. You can directly run maven projects from the IDE itself.